# Can we connect oracle database with DVC ? and if yes then how?

Tags: oracle, dvc

I was trying to connect dvc with oracle database but unable to do it. So, Please can anyone help me with that.

Comment: DVC is a file-based system. It's not designed to integrate directly with relational databases.

Comment: So can we connect MLFlow with Oracle database?